# AWS Lambda function trigger on object creation in S3 does not work

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am doing an upload like this:

> curl -v -X PUT -T "test.xml" -H "Host: my-bucket-upload.s3-eu-central-1.amazonaws.com" -H "Content-Type: application/xml" https://my-bucket-upload.s3-eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/test.xml

The file gets uploaded and I can see it in my S3 bucket.

The trick is, when I try to create a lambda function to be triggered on creation, it never gets invoked. If I upload the file using the S3 web interface, it works fine. What am I doing wrong? Is there any clear recipe on how to do it?

Comment: There are various events for adding new objects. can you show the lambda trigger configuration?

Answer (score 3):

> Amazon S3 APIs such as PUT, POST, and COPY can create an object. Using
>   these event types, you can enable notification when an object is
>   created using a specific API, or you can use the s3:ObjectCreated:*
>   event type to request notification regardless of the API that was used
>   to create an object.

- Check the notification event setup on the bucket
- Go to bucket on AWS management console
- Click the properties tab on the bucket
- Click the Events to check the notification event setup

**Case 1:**

- **s3:ObjectCreated:***  - Lambda should be invoked regardless of PUT, POST or COPY

**Other case:-**

- If the event is setup for specific HTTP method, use that method on
  your CURL command to create the object on S3 bucket. This way it
  should trigger the Lambda function

Answer (score 3):

Make sure the prefix you're adding contains safe special characters mentioned [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/object-keys.html#:%7E:text=and%20other%20APIs.-,Safe%20characters,-The%20following%20character). As per AWS documentation, some [characters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/object-keys.html#:%7E:text=Characters%20that%20might%20require%20special%20handling) require special handling. Please be mindful of that.

Also, I noticed modifying the trigger on lambda page doesn't get applied until you delete the trigger and new one (even if it is same). Learned hard way. AWS does behaves weird sometime.

Answer (score 1):

Check the prefix in bucket/properties.
If there is a world like `foo/`, that means that only the objects inside the `foo` folder will trigger the evert to lambda.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue, The problem was with the function name itself. Try to check the value of the prefix to see if that matches perfectly with the resource.

If the resource is: `resource/`
and prefix is `/test`

then the actual folder path becomes: `resource//test`

just remove the '/' before `test` and it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Faced similar issues and figured our that the folder names should not have spaces.

Answer (score -1):

Currently Under S3 there is option to Send notifications to Amazon EventBridge for all events in this bucket. `Turn on`